# token to unsigned printing odd values

Tags: c, struct, token, strtol, strtoull

As the title suggested I am getting some weird returns from strtoul, I have tested just by using strcpy to store the data as a string and it is giving the correct value, but as soon as I try and change it to an unsigned int by using strtoul() I am getting a weird result and can't find a way to fix it. my code is as follows:

```
void loadData(TennisStoreType* ts, char* customerFile, char* stockFile) {

   FILE *customerdata;
   FILE *stockdata;
   const char *DEL = ",\n\t\r";
   CustomerNodeType newdata;
   int datapos = 0;
   char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   char *remainder;
   char *token;
   char *cantload = "Can not load data from ";
   char *errorload = "Invalid data entry in ";
   char *canload = "Loading data from ";

   customerdata = fopen(customerFile, "r");
   stockdata = fopen(stockFile, "r");

   /* checks if the file can open*/
   if (customerdata == NULL) {

      fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", cantload, customerFile);

   } else {

      printf("%s%s\n", canload, customerFile);

      while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, customerdata) != NULL) {

         token = strtok(buffer, DEL);

         while(token != NULL) {

            /* this function checks weather the information is valid for
            the data position entered*/
            if (validCustData(datapos, token)) {

               /* Where abouts in the structure to load the data to*/
               switch (datapos) {
                  case 0:
                     strcpy(newdata.custID, token);
                     printf("successfully added %s in custID\n",     newdata.custID);
                 break;

                  case 1:
                     /*my own check to allow surnames to be entered over 12 characters
                     as in reality they do exist but it will only accept the first
                     12 characters and enter them into the structure

                     if (strlen(token) <= SURNAME_MAX) {
                        strcpy(newdata.surname, token);
                     } else {
                        strncpy(newdata.surname, token, SURNAME_MAX);
                        newdata.surname[SURNAME_MAX] = '\0';
                     }
                     printf("successfully added %s in surname\n", newdata.surname);
                     break; */


                      strcpy(newdata.surname, token);
                     printf("successfully added %s in surname\n", newdata.surname);
                     break;

                  case 2:
                     strcpy(newdata.firstName, token);
                     printf("successfully added %s in first name\n", newdata.firstName);
                     break;

                  case 3:
                     strcpy(newdata.address, token);
                     printf("successfully added %s in address\n", newdata.address);
                     break;

                  case 4:
                     strcpy(newdata.suburb, token);
                     printf("successfully added %s in suburb\n", newdata.suburb);
                     break;

                  case 5:
                     newdata.postCode = strtoul(token, &remainder, POSTCODE_LEN);
                     printf("successfully added %lu in postcode\n", newdata.postCode);
                     remainder = NULL;
                     break;

                  case 6:
                     newdata.phoneNum = strtoul(token, &remainder, PHONENUM_LEN);
                     printf("successfully added %lu in phone number\n", newdata.phoneNum);
                     remainder = NULL;
                     break;
               }

            } else {
               fprintf(stderr,"%s%s '%s'\n", errorload, customerFile, token);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               return;
            }


            if (datapos == DATA_POSITIONS) {
               datapos = 0;
            } else {
               datapos = datapos + 1;
            }

            token = strtok(NULL, DEL);
         }
      }
   }

   if (stockdata == NULL) {

      fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", cantload, stockFile);

   } else {

      /* to do */

      printf("%s%s\n", canload, stockFile);
   }
}
```

the data that is being loaded in is datapos = 5: and token = 3333: and the result that is printing is... "successfully added 255 in postcode".

as stated above, without changing the input and changing case 5: to strcpy() instead of strtoul() works but I can not do this as it does not follow the flags -pedantic -ansi and -Wall. which it needs to 100%.

ps: if needed POSTCODE_LEN is defined as 4 and I have included both stdlib.h and string.h

Comment: It seems you don't need the value of `remainder`, so you can just pass `NULL` as the second argument to `strtoul`.

Comment: It's currently just there to catch if there is non numerical characters just encase I need sometime in the future. high chance though I will remove and change to NULL, thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to strtoul is not the string length (the whole string us always used) - but the number base (aka radix).  Try passing in 10 instead of 4.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `strtoul` doesn't necessarily use the whole string, it only uses the string up to the first non-numerical character (that's why there is an `end pointer` argument to it: such that you can figure out whether the entire string could be parsed as a number).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did read the library of strtoul() but misinterpreted that, that makes a lot of sense now, I knew it was something tiny, 100% working, you made me very happy :)